# Why does calling GL.Color4 result in a blank screen?

Tags: opengl, textures

I am learning OpenGL using OpenTK and VB.NET. I made a square with a texture:

```
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 0.0)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(1.0, 0.0)
    GL.Vertex3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(1.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
    GL.End()
```

This works fine and produces this image:

[image]

When I add `GL.Color4`, the whole screen is completely blank. This is what my code looks like:

```
    GL.Color4(100, 100, 100, 255)
    GL.Begin(BeginMode.Quads)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 0.0)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(1.0, 0.0)
    GL.Vertex3(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(1.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
    GL.TexCoord2(0.0, 1.0)
    GL.Vertex3(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0)
    GL.End()
```

Here is an additional piece of code:

```
    GL.ShadeModel(ShadingModel.Smooth)
    GL.ClearColor(Color.Black)
    GL.ClearDepth(1.0)

    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D)
    GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.One)
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend)

    GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the functionality you're learning (OpenGL's *immediate mode*, using glBegin, et cetera) is deprecated in modern OpenGL and may not necessarily be the best investment of your time unless you cannot run modern OpenGL.

Comment: What Josh said, but also, are you sure those values to `GL.Color` aren't supposed to be in `[0,1]` ?  e.g. `GL.Color(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0)` ?  I can't find any worthwhile API docs on OpenTK so I haven't been able to check.

Comment: Using GL.Color4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0) works. It is strange that Color4 has overloaded function for integer and it is also what NeHe tutorial is using (integer).

Comment: Presumably the integer overrides should utilize things like [glColor4ui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318442(v=vs.85).aspx) under the hood.

Comment: Didn't know there even were overloads; I couldn't find squat for API documentation for OpenTK. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GL.Color*` functions can only be used between `GL.Begin` and `GL.End.` Your code sample has the lone `GL.Color4` call *before* `GL.Begin`. If you move it inside the begin/end block, you should see things again.

The most-likely reason this has led to a blank screen is that you're actually putting OpenGL into an error state and you're not retrieving any errors from OpenGL. If you had error handling code in place, you'd likely be seeing a message to the effect of "`glColor` must be called between `glBegin` and `glEnd`."